# Buscar uma imagem em um banco de dados MySQL com php e depois salvar essa imagem em outra tabela do mesmo banco

Tags: php, mysql, imagem

Estou fazendo um aplicativo para salvar imagens, quando o usuário não escolhe nenhuma imagem é salvo no banco de dados uma imagem padrão que é selecionada em outra tabela do banco de dados, porém na hora de salvar a imagem no banco, o php retorna o seguinte erro:

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ',,,,,'????' at line 1**

Segue o código que busca a imagem no banco e que exibe ela:

Busca:

```
    $query = "select imagem from imagem_padrao";
    $imagem_padrao = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $imagem_padrao = mysqli_fetch_row($imagem_padrao);
    $imagem_pronta = $imagem_padrao[0];
```

Insert:

```
   $query = ("insert into tamanho (foto_aparelho) values ('".$imagem_pronta."')");
   mysqli_query($con,$query) or die (mysqli_error($con);
```

Acredito que o erro está acontecendo na hora de inserir a imagem em formato array no banco de dados, porém não sei como resolver.

Comment: Acho que o problema está em como está definindo a query, troque o `$query = ("insert into tamanho (foto_aparelho) values ('".$imagem_pronta."')");` para `$query = "insert into tamanho (foto_aparelho) values ('".$imagem_pronta."')";`, removendo o primeiro `(` e último `)`.

Comment: Desculpa o erro não está na sintaxe do insert, esse é um erro meu de digitação, vou editar o post.

Comment: Tem que digitar o código corretamente pois muitas vezes vemos gente quebrando a cabeça e o erro está exatamente na digitação do código.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema de outra forma, em vez de armazenar a foto padrão em uma tabela do banco de dados, deixei ela como sendo um arquivo de imagem dentro da pasta do servidor da aplicação, daí funcionou como o esperado.